# Powershell: script will not run correct in parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I have the following script. It will run without a problem when it is not in parallel. But when I add `-Parallel` it throws all kinds of errors. The primary error seems to relate to `Cannot index into a null array`. I using PS 7.3.3. Any suggestions?

### Non-parallel portion of script (start of script)

```
$fileList=(get-childitem -filter *.tif -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match '^[0-9]{3} (B|F) [A-Z]{2} ..K..b [0-9]{2}.*'}).Name
$fileNumbers=($fileList.Substring(0,3) | Sort-Object | Get-Unique)

$fileArr=New-Object 'Object[,]' $fileNumbers.length,5

for ($i=0; $i -lt $fileNumbers.length; $i++) {
    $fileArr[$i,0]=$fileNumbers[$i]
    
    $iStr="{0:d3}" -f ($i+1)

    $backFullName=@()
    $backName=@()
    $frontFullName=@()

    $backFullName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr B *.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).FullName
    $frontFullName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr F CC*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).FullName
    $backName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr B*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).Name
    $frontName+=(Get-ChildItem -filter "$iStr F CC*.tif" -recurse | Sort-Object).Name


    if ($backName[0] -eq $null) {
        $backLabel=$null
    }
    else {
        $backLabel=("BRP "+$backName[0].Substring(16,2)+" "+$istr)
    }

    if ($frontName[0] -eq $null) {
        $frontLabel=$null
    }
    else {
        $frontLabel=("BRP "+$frontName[0].Substring(16,2)+" "+$istr)
    }

    $fileArr[$i,1]=$backFullName[0]
    $fileArr[$i,2]=$frontFullName[0]
    $fileArr[$i,3]=$backLabel
    $fileArr[$i,4]=$frontLabel
}
```

---

### Parallel portion of the script (second half of script)

```
    0..($fileNumbers.length-1) | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    if ($using::fileArr[$_,3] -eq $null -and $using::fileArr[$_,4] -ne $null) {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,4]
    }
    elseif ($using::fileArr[$_,3] -ne $null -and $using::fileArr[$_,4] -eq $null) {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,3]        
    }
    else {
        $label=$using::fileArr[$_,3]        
    }

    $locationA=Get-Random

    Convert +append $using::fileArr[$_,2] $using::fileArr[$_,1] x:\$locationA.jpg
    $height=[string](([int](identify -format "%h" x:\$locationA.jpg)+400))
    $width=(identify -format "%w" x:\$locationA.jpg)
    $halfWidth=([int]$width*.4)
    $dimensions=$width+"x"+$height

    $locationB=Get-Random

    convert x:\$locationA.jpg -gravity north -extent $dimensions x:\$locationB.jpg

    $str="text $halfWidth,50 '$label'"

    convert  x:\$locationB.jpg -pointsize 300  -gravity southwest -draw "$str" x:\$label.jpg
    Remove-Item x:\$locationA.jpg
    Remove-Item x:\$locationB.jpg

} -ThrottleLimit 12
```

---

After changing `$using::fileArr` to `$using:fileArr`, I received the following error:

[image]

Comment: The prefix should be `$using:` , not `$using::` - see [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by entering the following in the first line of the parallel block:

```
$fileArr=$using:fileArr
```

Once I wrote this line, I no longer needed $using:fileArr in the rest of the block. I simply used `$fileArr`.